# What is normal write lock percentage for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance

When we started to use MongoDB write lock percentage was 0.2%, now it is 1.5%. What is the normal range for it? Should I worry that it grows?

Comment: It depends on your data. Mine was exactly around 0.3% and now is 10% after two months. You should see your index size, number of inserts, updates, or queries you have per second. And if you have other ops that locks MongoDB. Also take a look at you iostat but I doubt it. It should be when it tries to fits the index into your RAM. Is this Replica set? If yes do you do your queries from secondaries? Also take a look at this page: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/

Answer (score 3):

Which version of MongoDB are you using?

May be this specific post might help you:

http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/44605fc5193349d2

http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/9e62c19aa3d0448f

http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/b619daa74bb3192a

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB lock percentage will vary greatly between databases.
Normal lock percentage definition depends on the DB usage.

Write heavy databases might see values >50% 
While read intensive databases can have values <10%